# Dynamic memory allocation in a matrix C

Tags: c

i really need your help. I'm trying to use dynamic memory in my matrix readed by a csv file. My code worked well with predefined size. It also worked with dynamic memory but only with malloc using "the correct" size. I don't know how to malloc with a value that make sense, and realloc while is reading the file. Any help is useful

```
void carregarMatrizes(TabelaIRS *tabelaIRS) {
    char *token, *pEnd, line[200];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    float num;

    FILE * tabNaoCasado = fopen("Ficheiros/tabelaIRSNAOCASADO.csv", "r");
    if (tabNaoCasado == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nOcorreu um erro ao abrir o ficheiro!\n\n");
    } else {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof (line), tabNaoCasado) && (token = strtok(line, ";")) != NULL) {
            while (token != NULL) {
                num = strtof(token, &pEnd);
                tabelaIRS->tabIRSNaoCasado[i][j] = num;
                token = strtok(NULL, ";");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        tabelaIRS->linhasNaoCasado = i;
        tabelaIRS->colunasNaoCasado = j;
    }
    fclose(tabNaoCasado);
```

the struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float **tabIRSNaoCasado,
    **tabIRSCasado1Titular,
    **tabIRSCasado2Titulares;
    int linhasNaoCasado, colunasNaoCasado,
    linhas1Titular, colunas1Titular,
    linhas2Titulares, colunas2Titulares;
} TabelaIRS;
```

i tried this code. and it works, but in my project this is the size of the default tabel [37][7]. this tabel could change is size. so i wanna malloc the minimum value and realloc while i'm reading the file, to include future changes.

```
tabelaIRS.tabIRSNaoCasado = malloc(37 * sizeof (float *));
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        tabelaIRS.tabIRSNaoCasado[i] = malloc(7 * sizeof (float));
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Show a minimal complete sample and explain what is wrong with it or what cases it doesn't support, and exactly what it needs to do instead.

Comment: @underscore_d done. at least i tried. sorry my native language is portuguese :/